# How to implement DbContext as an interface? Final goal is to use Moq for Unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

This is my non-working code so far. I have done all research that my understanding allows.
I might be missing something silly. I am new to c# and .Net environment.

Everything is good with the LibraryContext class. The problem is that I can not make use of the interface. When I load it to as services in Startup.cs and then call it in the controllers it gives errors. Updating the question with `Startup.cs` and `BooksController.cs` snippets.

First error is in `LibraryContext.cs`:

`LibraryContext' does not implement interface member 'ILibraryContext.SaveChangesAsync()' [LibraryApi].`

And then in `BooksController.cs` :

`'ILibraryContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no accessible extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'ILibraryContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [LibraryApi]csharp(CS1061)`

...

`LibraryContext.cs`

```
public interface ILibraryContext : IDisposable
  {
    public DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
  }


  public class LibraryContext : DbContext, ILibraryContext
  {
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options)
          : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().ToTable("Book");
      modelBuilder.Entity<Reader>().ToTable("Reader");
    }
  }
```

`Startup.cs`

```
    {
      services.AddScoped<ILibraryContext>(provider => provider.GetService<LibraryContext>());
    ...
    }
```

`BooksController.cs`

```
  {
    private readonly ILibraryContext _context;

    public BooksController(ILibraryContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }
...
```

Comment: What about your code is non-working?

Comment: Everything is good with the LibraryContext class. The problem is that I can not make use of the interface. When I load it to as services in Startup.cs and then call it in the controllers it gives errors. First error is `LibraryContext' does not implement interface member 'ILibraryContext.SaveChangesAsync()' [LibraryApi]`. Updating the question with Startup.cs and one of the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not everything is good with the 'LibraryContext' class. The clue is in the errormessage: `LibraryContext' does not implement interface member 'ILibraryContext.SaveChangesAsync()'` .

You could add it like this:

`async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => await base.SaveChangesAsync();`

or

`async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

You were probably expecting `SaveChangesAsync` in the base class `DbContext` to fulfil the interface contract, but interfaces don't work like that.

You could add an implementation of `SaveChangesAsync` in your `LibraryContext` which just calls `base.SaveChangesAsync` and returns its result and thereby fulfil the interface contract.